# php: compare date with if condition

Tags: php, xml

I am in a very strange situation. i have xml feed and i am storing xml feed data in database by using for loop to read one xml value at a time. Date value in xml is look like this.

```
<date>Friday, 02 Sep 2016 00:00:00</date>
```

I have written the below the code to compare the date.

```
 $todays = date("Y-m-d");
 $newdates = strtotime ( '-4 day' , strtotime ($todays) ) ;
    echo $today = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdates );

some code for xml feed 

$dates = $item[$i]->date;
echo $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates));

if($today != $newDate ) {
               break;
             }

else{
Store in database
}
```

Here is the output.
2016-09-01
2016-09-02

I can see in xml there is many data for September 1st. But data is not returning if i compare the with if condition.
Any advise what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What does `var_dump($dates); show?

Comment: var_dump($dates) return this . object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (0) { } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast that SimpleXMLElement to a string to get that value

```
$dates = (string) $item[$i]->date;
```

I wrote a simpler piece of code that should do the same thing your code is attempting to do.

```
$fourDaysAgo = new DateTime('-4 days');

// some code for xml feed 

$xmlDate = //(string) $item[$i]->date;
$date = new DateTime($xmlDate);

if($fourDaysAgo->format('Y-m-d') == $date->format('Y-m-d') ) {
    echo 'Store in database';    
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/634977)

Comment: I tried that but if condition is still not working. i am getting the same output and in vardump i can see the date.

Comment: string(28) "Friday, 02 Sep 2016 00:00:00"

Comment: var_dump($newDate) is string(10) "2016-09-02"

Comment: var_dump($today) is string(10) "2016-09-01"

Answer (score 2):

See this in your code?

> $dates = $item[$i]->date;

You can explode variable $dates to get rid of "Friday" and just focus on the date "02 Sep 2016 00:00:00".

```
$dates = $item[$i]->date;
$dates = explode(",", $dates);
```

And replace

> echo $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates));

with,

```
echo $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[1]));
```

This should be good.
Let us know if it works on your end.

Answer (score 2):

Modified your original code to below:

```
$todays = date("Y-m-d");
$newdates = strtotime ( '-4 day' , strtotime ($todays) ) ;
    echo $today = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdates );

// some code for xml feed 

$dates = $item[$i]->date;
$dates = explode(",", $dates);
echo $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[1]));

if($today != $newDate ) {
               break;
             }

else{
Store in database
}
```